Cypress: How to select parent's sibling's children based on children of parent?
I am finding a selector for  tag i.e href="/chlamydia-treatment" based on id="dropdown-sexual-health".
So basically trying to find a selector for children of my parent's sibling.
<li xpath="1">
   <a class="" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button">
      <div class="dropdown-item-menu" id="dropdown-sexual-health">Sexual health
          <span class="boots-icon-ic-boots-chevron-thin-up"></span>
      </div>
   </a>
   <ul class="header-navbar__submenu header-navbar__show-menu-item">
       <li><a class="" href="/chlamydia-treatment">Chlamydia treatment</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>


The test code could be just as you describe it in the title, but I would expect you need to wait for visibility of the sub-menu.
cy.get('#dropdown-sexual-health')
  .parent()
  .next()
  .as('subMenu')
  .click()

cy.get('@subMenu')
  .find('[href="/chlamydia-treatment"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()

I use an alias to "record" the sub-menu element after finding it, but you can also repeat the first three query lines if you prefer.

I also see it's in a NavBar, so instead of click maybe you need to hover. Cypress has difficulty with hover, I would use cypress-real-events in this case.
cy.get('#dropdown-sexual-health')
  .parent()
  .next()
  .as('subMenu')
  .realHover()

cy.get('@subMenu')
  .find('[href="/chlamydia-treatment"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()


You can use xPath
This is how xpath works:
To go from a node to a sibling you should use : "folowwing-sibling" or "preceeding-sibling"
To go from a node to a parent you should use : parent
To go from a node to a children you should use : child
So your xPath will look something like this :
//your-first-node/parent::your-parent-localiser/preceeding-sibling::your-sibling-localiser/children::your-children-localiser

So final result could be like this
//*[id="dropdown-sexual-health"]/parent::*/following-sibling::*/children::*  


cy.parent() can be used to find the parent element of the selected element.
cy.get('#dropdown-sexual-health') // yields dropdown element
  .parent('a') // yield the anchor parent element 

cy.siblings() can be used to query for sibling elements.
cy.get('#dropdown-sexual-health')
  .parent('a')
  .siblings('ul') // yield the unordered list element(s) that are siblings of the above anchor parent

cy.find() can be used to query element(s) for child elements. (cy.children() could also be used, but I prefer cy.find())
cy.get('#dropdown-sexual-health')
  .parent('a')
  .siblings('ul')
  .find('[href="/chlamydia-treatment"]'); // yields the child anchor element

